# OneLogin Maximum Call and pagination

Tags: api, url, onelogin

I can't find my answer so i'm asking you. I was wondering if pagination calls using "**next_link**" with OneLogin API would count as a call for the limit ?

example :
If I have **300 000** users to fetch from the API every 30 minutes. I would have to make (300 000 /50) **6000** calls using pagination (limit for an account is ***5000***/hour). 
PS: maximum user per query is 50.

Thanks un advance for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

After testing, the pagination call count as "a call". So limit apply for each call even using the **next_link** of pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination counts as a call.

But to solve the underlying issue, if your account is a large one (if you have 300K users, it sounds like it is) contact your customer success contact.

That 5K/hour limit is the default but it can easily be raised for large customers.